# Can I have another publicly accessible directory on Wordpress server?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a Wordpress site hosted by BlueHost. Is there a way I can create a new subdirectory under public_html that would not redirect to my Wordpress site? Do I need to modify the .htaccess file?

UPDATE:

Here's the .htaccess file currently:

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~user/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~user/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: it all depends on what you have in your htaccess file, but since you haven't shared it, not sure how you expect people to be able to help you... more details please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

The above rewrite conditional checks validate that URL rewriting should **only** be done when the requested resource is *not* a readable directory or file. So if you have your `public_html` laid out as such:

```
public_html/
    wp-admin/
         ...
    wp-content/
         ...
    wp-includes/
         ...
    my-sub-site/
         index.php
         ...
    .htaccess
    index.php
    ...
```

Then you should be able to access the `my-sub-site/index.php` without problems, as it exists and is readable (validate `rwx` access rights if it is not).